# PSTricks doesn't work in Linux

Tags: pstricks, ubuntu, eps

I'm tryng to compile in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 + Texlive-full) a document using `latex>dvips>ps2pdf`. This document include graphics in .eps and has a pspicture code.

When I compile this document in Windows (with MikTek distribution); i don't have any problem;  but, when i try in Ubuntu, the document doesn't compile correctly: Don't recognize the .eps file and the pspicture code, and print in the document expressions like

```
psset],pst-gradfillcolor=white %For .eps file
psset],pst-gradshowgrid=falsepsset].... %For pspicture.
```

The info about the error is (token from .log file)

```
(./Portada.tex
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+txsya on input line 4.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsya.fd
File: utxsya.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+txsyb on input line 4.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsyb.fd
File: utxsyb.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+rsfs on input line 4.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+txmia on input line 4.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/utxmia.fd
File: utxmia.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+txsyc on input line 4.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsyc.fd
File: utxsyc.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
File: Logo/FCFM.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Logo/FCFM.eps>
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+txss on input line 8.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/ot1txss.fd
 File: ot1txss.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/txss/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.40245pt on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/txss/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.49997pt on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/txss/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.54997pt on input line 9.
File: Logo/DIMEC.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Logo/DIMEC.eps>)
(./Indice.tex [1

] (./T1RT.toc)
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `T1RT.toc'.

[1]) (./p1.tex


[1]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+txtt on input line 42.

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/ot1txtt.fd
File: ot1txtt.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)) (./p2.tex

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
Make it at least 20.48752pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

[2] (./p2factor.tex
! Argument of \begin has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.4 \begin
      {pspicture}(0,-3.1154687)(6.0146875,3.1154687)
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \begin was complete.
<to be read again> 
                  \par 
l.4 \begin
         {pspicture}(0,-3.1154687)(6.0146875,3.1154687)
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.7 ...r=color17b](3.176875,-2.3004687)(0.24,0.16)

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.8 ...or=color17b](3.156875,1.6195313)(2.36,0.84)

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.9 \psdots[dotsize=0.12](
                      3.176875,1.6395313)
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.10 ...04cm,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](
                                              3.176875,1.5995313)(3.1768...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.11 \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](
                           3.196875,0.77953124)(3.176875,-2.3204687)
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.12 ...ecolor=red](3.146875,1.5895313)(1.55,0.55)

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.13 \psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color49](
                                             3.196875,-2.3004687)(4.5768...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.14 ...3.196875,-1.2804687){1.08}{49.76364}{90.0}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.


! Package keyval Error: [ undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 ...cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}
                                              (3.156875,1.6195313)(2.276...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.15 ...cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}
                                              (3.156875,1.6195313)(2.276...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.15 ...cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.0]{->}
                                              (3.156875,1.6195313)(2.276...
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

PD: I'm Texmaker user; but, i don't know how to compile in terminal

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A possibility could be bad line termination; you may start checking it for the file `p2factor.tex`

Comment: looks like an old TeX distribution (Ubuntu often comes with TL2009). However, create a minimal example which shows the problem and put `\listfiles` as first line into your example and then send the file list, which is at the end of the log file.

Comment: to run a TeX file in a terminal open one from Ubuntu's menu, go with `cd <dir>` into the directory of the document and then run `latex <file>`

Comment: What are the first lines of `p2factor.tex` and what is the first error message *exactly*?